# Content Organizer - Creates duplicates in the destination library

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, document-library, content-organizer

We have created 2 libraries, one of which have a `Content Organizer` set on, to send it to the 2nd Library. In the `Content Organizer Settings`, we decided for duplicates to append unique characters at the end of duplicates filenames.

But I saw recently that we have duplicates of those files in the destination library, without any clear reason. Looks like the file is moved for the first time, but the properties of the item are not entirely filled out. Fifteen minutes later, the duplicate is created, with the random characters at the end of the file name.

Any idea why duplicates are created?

Edit: Just saw that 2 documents were transfered in the 2nd Library with missing properties, but the documents were not removed from the 1st Library, like if they were half processed. (Create the item in the destination Library, but stop before setting the properties & deleting it from the source Library) The user which created those documents did not see anything wrong while doing them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen file uploads happen almost immediately and then the metadata fields get added as a modification.  This has tripped up workflow that used a metadata field.  We had to adjust the workflow to pause until modified not equal to created.

Either reduce the metadata required or try to adjust when the workflow or timer job runs to less frequent.

Comment: We are not using any custom workflow in our case. It's the Content Organizer which is driving the file moves. And the Content Organizer Settings are set so that the document should not be moved until all required properties are fulfilled. 
I also tested for a file which the required metadata were not all entered, and it was never moved.

Comment: Doing some more searches, there was in fact a simple workflow, but not in the source, but the destination Library. It was checking out the document, so it may be possible that the check out was done before the metadata were changed as you said. It's been 5 days since I changed the workflow by adding a 5 minutes wait, and there's no more document which have the issue. So it looks like it was in fact the workflow which was causing the issue. I'll mark as resolved for now since it looks like it is and give the Bounty. I'll let know within the next week if the issue happened again. Anyway, Thanks!

Comment: 5 days later, and still no issue. So it is now safe to assume that the issue is resolved. (Longest time without issue before was 4 or 5 days, versus 12 days now) Thanks to you once more for your answer!